# What is correct MVM vs. MMV?

Tags: terminology, virology

I'm writing up a report and I see conflicts everywhere on the internet. Should it be Murine Minute Virus (MMV) or Minute Virus of Mice (MVM).

The followup question is does it really matter.

Comment: i would say no, but just an opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [International Committee on Taxonomy of Viruses](http://ictvonline.org/taxonomyHistory.asp?taxnode_id=20142982), it has had several official variations of that name over the years:

- *Minute mouse virus*
- *Minute of mice virus*
- *MVM Virus*
- *Minute virus of mice*
- *Mice minute virus*

The current (2014) accepted name is: *Rodent protoparvovirus 1*

"Does it really matter?" As long as you write in full the name you're using the first time you use it, people will know what you're talking about. However, for consistency amongst current literature, perhaps we should all strive to keep up with current taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Given the wide variety of academic sources using each abbreviation, it's fairly clear that there is no standardised usage; as such, as long as you state the full phrase the first time you use it and use whichever form you pick consistently throughout your report, it doesn't really matter which you use.

To avoid confusion, I would recommend mentioning that both are used to refer to the same thing the first time you introduce the term.